# "Robot Framework Support" plugin features doesn't work when code distributed in hierarchy model

Tags: intellij-idea, robotframework

I am new to robot framework and trying to setting up my development environment. I am using InteliJ Idea(2017.2 Community Version) with Robot Framework Support( Version: 0.16.4) plugin.

Plugin promising features like Code completion support, Jump to keyword definition, Find usages / rename of keywords and resources,...etc works well when code is distributed within same folder.

I am trying implement page object pattern with below hierarchy,
[image]

When code is distributed as above in different folders, except syntax highlighting all other features plugin provides doesn't work. I mean like code completion, Jump to keyword definition,..etc

Appreciate any clue  to resolve above concern

Comment: Do these features work when you have a simpler project setup?

Comment: yes, when keyword and test robot files are on same folder, these features are working

Comment: And what is the simplest example that doesn't work?

Comment: Basically when code distributed in above order as in attached pic, IDE fails to create linkages, intense, code refactoring,...etc

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. The simplest example would be, for example, refer to a file 1 directory up. Or 1 up and then 1 down. Etc. Does running robot itself work in this setup?

Comment: Robot code get executed without any issue

Comment: I checked referring file 1 directory up but that also not working

Comment: Can you share the code in your LoginTestCase.robot?